# spark sql alter table to add more columns

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I don't know how the add columns clause works in spark sql. Here is my code. But it has parserexception. What's wrong with it?

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE deltaTable ADD COLUMNS (abc LongType, dea LongType AFTER ttt)")
```

Error is:

```
ParseException  
    /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
        775         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
        776         """
    --> 777         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
        778 
        779     def table(self, tableName):
    
    /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1302 
       1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    -> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
       1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

Comment: can you add error msg cause it looks like the bracket before abc is not closed

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi, I forgot to type one bracket here. I added the error in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LongType is dataframe datatype not spark SQL datatype which if you scroll down in your error message you will see

So in spark sql use below query

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE deltatable ADD COLUMNS (abc Long, dea Long AFTER ttt)")
```